# Make Programs and Features 'Change' button prompt for authentication

Tags: uac, microsoft-office

I am looking for a way to have the 'Change' button in Programs and Features pop a UAC authentication dialog such as when installing an application for the first time. Currently, we don't deploy PowerPoint due to company policy, but users have the ability to add it themselves via Programs and Features. Some users need the application, so removing it altogether isn't an option either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could deny all the users privileges from the account settings, so , everytime you need to install something a promp window will ask for administrator privileges to log in

Comment: That is how the workstations are currently configured. Office requires administrator privileges to install, but the users are able to add/remove office components without admin rights.